# Giving permission to a ftp FILE java

Tags: java, android, file-permissions, chmod, ftp-client

i have a class in android that connect with the ftp, and store an image, that works perfect the problem is when i am trying to move the image to another directory( i use a php page to moderate that image) it doesnt have permission to handle it, i want to put the permission to 0777 but only the "java code" can do it but i dont know how,

I am using FTPClient library

this is my code

```
 File imageFile = new File(url[0]); 



         FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();   ftpClient.connect(InetAddress.getByName("myserver"));
         ftpClient.login("login", "pass");

         ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("directory");
         ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
         BufferedInputStream buffIn=null;
         buffIn=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(imageFile));
         ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
         ftpClient.storeFile(url[1]+".jpg", buffIn);
         buffIn.close();
         ftpClient.logout();
         ftpClient.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it by command

```
 ftpClient.storeFile(url[1]+".jpg", buffIn);
         boolean a = ftpClient.sendSiteCommand("chmod " + "777 " + "/absolutepath/"+url[1]+".jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [FTPClient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) and FTPFile API
You can do something like that :

```
...
ftpClient.storeFile(url[1]+".jpg", buffIn);
FTPFile file = ftpClient.mlistFile(url[1]+".jpg");
file.setPermission(FTPFile.USER_ACCESS, FTPFile.READ_PERMISSION, true);
file.setPermission(FTPFile.USER_ACCESS, FTPFile.WRITE_PERMISSION, true);
...
```

Comment: It doesnt change the permission, the file is the same but it doesnt change the permission

Comment: It is certainly because your FTP server does not allow you to change file permissions, have you access to server logs? (Ps: your edit with an array and `listFiles` might work too, but in case of one file, it's easier and it runs faster to use mlistFile (as `mlistFile` is reusing the control connection, `listFile` has to open a data connection))

Comment: i made it by commands since i didnt find any information about how to put a FTPFile in the ftpclient or just update the FTPfile so you need to do it with chmod