# What permissions do i need for a java ftpclient?

Tags: java, android, ftp, ftp4j

I'm new in java and I'm working on an android app that connects to a ftp server .I'm having problems because i don't know exactly what permissions do I need to add to AndroidManifest.xml .I also have problems because I can't get it to connect to the server.
MainActivity.java :

```
   package com.mycompany.myapp;
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient;
import android.widget.*;
import it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.*;
import java.io.*;public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        try
        {
            client.connect("192.168.1.1", 21);
            client.login("root", "root");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Connected!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (FTPException e)
    {}
    catch (IllegalStateException e)
    {}
    catch (IOException e)
    {}
    catch (FTPIllegalReplyException e)
    {}
}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mycompany.myapp" >
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

main.xml:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">
```

Comment: Have you checked other posts like this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040563/giving-permission-to-a-ftp-file-java ?

Comment: Yes and I'm not having trouble with the permissions on the server.My problem is with the permissions that the android app has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you should need is INTERNET.  Although depending on what you want to do, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE may make sense.